# Как правильно в libgdx отрисовывать кнопку Button?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Я создал объект класса Button

```
Drawable drawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(buttonTexture));
Button b = new Button(drawable);
```

Как его теперь правильно рисовать, указывая координаты? Или с кнопкой не всё так просто как с текстурой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется стоит начинать с красивых кнопок сразу, для этого существует кнопка ImageButton.

```
TextureAtlas mainMenuAtlas = Assets.manager.get("mainmenu/mainMenu.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);//если есть менеджер ассетов - загрузите ваш атлас с изображениями
Skin buttonsSkin = new Skin(mainMenuAtlas);

ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle connectToHost = new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
connectToHost.up = buttonsSkin.getDrawable("menu-connect-btn");//кнопка не нажата
connectToHost.over = buttonsSkin.getDrawable("menu-connect-btn");
connectToHost.down = buttonsSkin.getDrawable("menu-connect-btn-down"); // кнопка нажата

ImageButton gameClientButton = new ImageButton(connectToHost);
gameClientButton.setSize(100, 200);// размер кнопки
gameClientButton.setPosition(10, 10); // позиция кнопки(с нижнего левого угла координаты считаются)
gameClientButton.addListener(new ClientListener()); //действие при нажатии
stage.addActor(gameClientButton ); //добавляем кнопку к сцене
```

Желательно завести себе две переменные которые будут хранить в себе разрешение экрана(ширину, высоту). И для масштабирования на разных устройствах с разными диагоналями либо использовать ViewPort(погуглите, это не сложно) либо все элементы указывать в процентах от размера экрана.

Кнопку создавайте и добавляйте к сцене в методе

```
@Override
public void show() { }
```

. В show() описываются элементы игры которые будут статическими.

Для того что бы по мере надобности менять кнопки, цвета кнопок и прочее - Объявляете кнопку и ее стиль перед методом show():

```
ImageButton button;
ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle buttonStyle;

@Override
 public void show() 
 {
 //назначаете позицию, размер, стиль вышеперечисленных кнопки и стиля
 }
```

Если же вы хотите ее менять, положение, и другие параметры:
В рендере все это можете делать просто

```
@Override
     public void render() 
     {
     if(needChangeVisible)
        {
           button.setVisibility(false); //если булевая переменная приняла значение true то прячем кнопку

           buttonStyle.up = buttonsSkin.getDrawable("menu-connect-btn");//Меняете изображение кнопки при не нажатом состоянии
        }
     }
```

Comment: Вы правы, мне нужен был именно ImageButton. Только вот мне кажется у меня кнопка не должна быть статической: 1) она должна уметь менять цвет; 2) неплохо, если она умела бы скрываться. Или я не прав? Что думаете, получится ли?

Comment: Пока я не заметил разницы между Button и ImageButton

Comment: Обновил ответ. Разница в том что ImageButton это кнопка с картинкой внутри. А  button - кнопка использующая стиль скина, и надпись внутри нее. ImageButton - для стилизованных кнопок, круглых, кривых , любых абсолютно

Comment: А от чего в данном случае главный класс наследовать? У меня от ApplicationListener, думаю это не правильно.

Comment: Хм, у вас что ли игра состоит из 1 экрана? каждый экран implement Screen класс.
Самый главный класс(в котором происходит загрузка ассетов , распределение экранов и прочее) наследуется от extends Game.