# Сделать кнопку в LibGDX

Tags: button, libgdx

Есть приложение, змейка, управляется с клаватуры, клавишами вверх-вниз-вправо-влево. Хотелось бы отрисовать 4 кнопки и привязать их к этим клавишам. Чтоб с тачксрина можно было играть.

Видел тут тему [Как правильно в libgdx отрисовывать кнопку Button?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428831/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2-libgdx-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-button)

Однако код который там, вставляеться в метод Show. У меня такого нет, есть метод Create, при вставлении в него, Assets в Assets.manager.get подчёркивает красным.

В интернете смотрел - там вообще кода чтоб создать джойстик на экране на 150 строк.

Неужели нет простого способа отрисовать кнопку, как в простом андроиде, что нибудь типа

```
ImageButton ibutton = new ImageButton("0, 0, @assets/vpravo.png, keys.down");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать json. Вот не большой пример кода:

```
private Stage stage;
private Skin skin;
private Table table = new Table();


stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/uiskin.json"));
final TextButton playTextButton=new TextButton("Play",skin);
final TextButton exitTextButton=new TextButton("Exit",skin);
final TextButton optionsTextButton = new TextButton("Options",skin);

table.setFillParent(true);
table.add(playTextButton).size(100,50);
table.add(optionsTextButton).size(100,50);
table.add(exitTextButton).size(100,50);
stage.addActor(table);
```